# Is $\max_{t\in[0,1]}\left | f'(t)\right |=0$ an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was wondering if 
$$\max_{t\in[0,1]}\left | f'(t)\right |=0$$

is an ODE. My script defines ODE as an equation of the form
$$F\colon U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\\
F(x,f(x),...,f^{(n)}(x))=0$$

where $U$ is open.

By definition it is not an ODE, because $f$ would depend on different arguments. But then again, a solution is requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed an ODE, but indirectly. Because

$$\max_{t\in[0,1]}|f'(t)|=0$$ is equivalent to

$$f'(t)=0,$$ and that yields $$f(t)=c$$ in $[0,1]$.

Comment: What do you mean by indirectly?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta: this is exactly explained in the next sentence.